# Create a record to manage with array

Tags: java

I have a problem, I'm trying to translate an algorithm for visual basic 6 in java and I was wondering if you can use a record with the carrier in java I trawled around but could not find concrete things, practically in the algorithm vb6 to translate is this;

```
Private Type struttura
nome As String
minimo As Integer
massimo As Integer
End Type

campsoSel() as struttura

campoSel(i).nome = "valori"
campoSel(i).minimo = 1
campoSel(i).massimo = 10
```

in java I did so I created a class named record:

```
public class Record 
{
public String nome;
public int minimo;
public int massimo;

}
```

Then in the main but I would also have done so elsewhere:

```
public class StrutturaRecord {    

public static void main(String[] args) 
{  
    int n = 2;

    Record campoSel[] = new Record[n];

    campoSel[i].nome = "ciao";
    campoSel[i].minimo = 1;
    campoSel[i].massimo = 10;



}

}
```

but it gives me this error

what is wrong?
you believe that you can do something like this in java?
thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `i` defined in main?

Comment: What error does it give you?

Answer (score 0):

The variable i is not defined.

In your main you created a non mutable array with two indexes.  If you want to access the first index of the array in java you follow this format:

```
nameOfArray[desiredIndex]
```

Comment: sorry I did not understand, could you do me a practical example of my code please let

Comment: campoSel[0].nome = "ciao";

Comment: In java I would use array lists instead. They are much easier to work with. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Well that exception is from when you created your record class. For the string nome in the class first set it to an empty string.